# Is the prepositional phrase acting as an adverb or adjective

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs, prepositional-phrases

Is the phrase "after contracting covid-19" acting as an adjective or adverb in the sentence below?

> Unvaccinated teacher infects students after contracting COVID-19

Comment: Ask yourself whether "contracting COVID-19 modifies "unvaccinated teacher" or the verbal phrase "infects students".

Comment: https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-7/prepositions/lesson-5/adverb-prepositional-phrases and https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-adverb-1691528

Comment: "After contracting COVID-19" is a preposition phrase functioning as a temporal adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It seems like it can go both ways

Comment: The unvaccinated teacher contracts the virus and *afterwards* (time) infects the students.

Comment: It answers the question "when".

Comment: @gotube so that would make it an adverb instead of adjective?

Comment: @Anna Yes. Adjectives only modify nouns. Adverbs can modify almost anything else.

Comment: @gotube can't an adjective modify the noun when answering "when?"

Comment: @Anna What do you mean by "the noun"? What noun do you think "after contracting COVID-19" could modify?

Comment: @gotube by the noun I mean "after contracting COVID-19"  describing the noun "unvaccinated teacher"

Comment: @Anna You cannot ask a "when" question about a noun: "When did the unvaccinated teacher?" That's not a grammatical question. The question is about "Unvaccinated teacher infects students": "When did the unvaccinated teacher infect students? After contracting COVID-19."

Comment: @gotube in Justice Department to announce lawsuit against Texas over law, is "against Texas" an adverb or adjective describing lawsuit